# ChartJS: build custom JavaScript file with only chart types I need

Tags: chart.js

I want to use [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) on my website, but with smaller filesize if possible, with only the chart types I need. I downloaded ChartJS and build to get /dist folder. I found [bundle-optimization](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundle-optimization) but I do not understand what to do now.

Is there a easy way to remove unneeded chart types and get a smaller JavaScript file (chart.js)? How do I remove "Radar Chart" out of chart.js? I would be glad about any help. :)